# Comapare get_user_meta value

Tags: php, hooks, user-meta, array

Got the below array result from the `get_user_meta()` WordPress hook

Review the array

Need to check value of all `val` key whether its value is 1 or not.

The `get_users()` array have the values :

```
Array
(
[0] => WP_User Object
    (
        [data] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ID] => 1
                [user_email] => test@test.com
            )


    )

[1] => WP_User Object
    (
        [data] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ID] => 2
                [user_email] => abc@xyz.com
            )


    )
)
```

`get_user_meta()` array values:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [first_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => john
            )

        [val] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [first_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => mark
            )

        [val] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
            )

    )

)
```

**Need to take value of `email` from `get_users()` where `get_user_meta()` `val` == 1**

I have tried this below solution but can can not get result.

```
$is_val = array_search(1,array_column($users,'val'));

if($is_val == 1) { wp_mail($to,$subject,$message,); }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use meta_key or meta_query to fetch users where get_user_meta() 'val' == 1

Option 1:

```
$users = get_users(array(
    'meta_key'     => 'val',  // your_meta_key
    'meta_value'   => '1',   // value you want to compare
    'meta_compare' => '=',
));
```

Option 2:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query'   =>array(
        array(
            'key' => 'val',  //your_meta_key
            'value' => 1,    // value of key to compare
            'compare' => "="
        ),
    )
);
$users = get_users( $args );
```

You can run through the loop to get email address of user and send email.

Comment: Can not get what you are trying to express...

Comment: Simply use meta_query parameter inside get_users function to fetch users. It will return users only having get_user_meta() val == 1